# How to export specific attributes from model in Maatwebsite Excel in Laravel 5.1

Tags: excel, export

I want to pick some attributes from model in Laravel using Maatwebsite Excel export (not the full model attributes). I'm doing something like this, it works fine but gives full attributes of model:

```
public function exportUserData(){

ob_end_clean();
ob_start();

$user= User::where('type', '=', 'writers')->get()->toArray();
Excel::create('users', function($excel) use($user) {
    $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($user) {
        $sheet->fromArray($user);
    });

})->download('xlsx');


}
```

I want $user->name, $user->email, ...

Answer (score 0):

How about you select first before where?

```
$user = User::select('name,'email')->where('type', '=', 'writers')->get()->toArray();
```